# Accessing C function from Node.js

Tags: c, node.js, node-ffi

I have a requirement where I have to access a C function and expose it as an API. I am supposed to deploy it on Node.js server. I don't know how to access C function using any node package. I have tried using `node-ffi` package but at the time of installation it gives me error:

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check
gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:295:17)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\niket_kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! node-ffi@0.5.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-ffi@0.5.7 install script.
```

Note that I am using Python 2.7 and Windows 7 (32-bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this package to install `node-ffi`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi. Notice that it's called *ffi*, not *node-ffi*.

Also make sure that you have the version 2.7.3 of Python. [`node-gyp`'s GitHub page](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) mentions that 2.7.3 is the recommended version for Windows operating system.

Comment: Did you try to use the suggested package? It works well in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to install ffi module.